# XSL printing just the first occurrence of selected node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet media="netscape" type="text/xsl" href="periodic.xsl"?>
<PERIODIC_TABLE>
  <ATOM STATE="GAS">
    <NAME>Hydrogen</NAME>
    <SYMBOL>H</SYMBOL>
    <ATOMIC_NUMBER>1</ATOMIC_NUMBER>
    <ATOMIC_WEIGHT>1.00794</ATOMIC_WEIGHT>
    <BOILING_POINT UNITS="Kelvin">20.28</BOILING_POINT>
    <MELTING_POINT UNITS="Kelvin">13.81</MELTING_POINT>
    <DENSITY UNITS="grams/cubic centimeter">
    <!-- At 300K, 1 atm -->0.0000899
    </DENSITY>
  </ATOM>
  <ATOM STATE="GAS">
    <NAME>Helium</NAME>
    <SYMBOL>He</SYMBOL>
    <ATOMIC_NUMBER>2</ATOMIC_NUMBER>
    <ATOMIC_WEIGHT>4.0026</ATOMIC_WEIGHT>
    <BOILING_POINT UNITS="Kelvin">4.216</BOILING_POINT>
    <MELTING_POINT UNITS="Kelvin">0.95</MELTING_POINT>
    <DENSITY UNITS="grams/cubic centimeter">
    <!-- At 300K -->0.0001785
    </DENSITY>
  </ATOM>
</PERIODIC_TABLE>
```

And I am trying to print just all values of "NAME" with this XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <xsl:value-of select="//ATOM/NAME" />
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is:

```
<html>Hydrogen</html>
```

While there should be also "Helium". I am aware that there are other ways to do this, like for example selecting "NAME" in the xml:template match attribute, but I need to know why of this behaviour, so I can learn how to use value-of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `select` attribute of a `value-of` element works identically to the [XPath `string()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string), which converts its parameter to a string.The documentation says this

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order.

So you are passing a set of two `NAME` nodes, and `select` is using only the first.

You could use a `for-each` element, but XSLT is best written with templates. This will do what you ask.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PERIODIC_TABLE/ATOM/NAME"/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NAME">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<html>HydrogenHelium</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Borodin's answer, the behavior is different in XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 2.0, the [xsl:value-of](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of) instruction creates a sequence.

By just changing the version number to 2.0 and using a 2.0 processor, you get the following output:

```
<html>Hydrogen Helium</html>
```